# Convert Html characters to their original character in WP7 with c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I need to change the following characters in french:

```
C&#39;est au tour d&#39;
```

to its original string as:

```
C'est au tour d'
```

How do i go about this? The string is displayed with a textblock control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var str = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("C&#39;est au tour d&#39;"); //System.Web
```

or

```
var str = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("C&#39;est au tour d&#39;"); //System.Net
```